# Antd Table not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to re-render a table to show "Tag" when the switches in my Antd table is flipped on. I think there is something wrong with the way the table renders.

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-star-0itd6

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  function onChange(checked) {
    const changeTable = tableData;
    if (changeTable[checked.key].switch === "") {
      changeTable[checked.key].switch = "Tag";
    } else {
      changeTable[checked.key].switch = "";
    }

    setTableData(changeTable);
    console.log(tableData);
  }
```

Comment: You mean by adding new tag on the Tags column, when switch will be on?

Answer (score 1):

In react, the previous state is compared shallowly.

Therefore, modifying the array without changing the reference won't trigger a render.

```
  function onChange(checked) {
    const changeTable = tableData;
    if (changeTable[checked.key].switch === '') {
      changeTable[checked.key].switch = 'Tag';
    } else {
      changeTable[checked.key].switch = '';
    }

    //                  v Won't render
    // setTableData(changeTable);
    setTableData([...changeTable]);
  }
```

[image: Edit hungry-jang-0oi9e]